# Исчезает текст по нажатию на item Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

В названии описана вся проблема, как ни странно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Привожу минимальный код, который возможно понадобится. Если нужно будет еще что-то, тогда дополню:

```
  @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.recent_activity) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RecentActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        if (id == R.id.rate_dialog) {
          //  rateApp = new DialogFragment();
           // rateApp.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "");
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Метод создания навигейшн вьюхи:

```
private void initNavigationDrawer() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer);
        //    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.hamburger);

        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }
```

Столкнулся с тем, что повсюду используют фрагмент со списком внутри, и я не понимаю зачем, если есть `menu`.

При выделении итема, текст на нём пропадает. Вот как-бы, и всё.

UPD: добавил то как это выглядит, на странную раскраску не обращайте внимания, это в стили учусь. Пока не нашел как стилизовать эту панель -_-.

UPD: Прилагаю стили

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppDefault" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/head_bottom_sheet_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/blue_gradient</item>
        <!-- Other -->
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    </style>

    <style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabTextAppearance</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">6dp</item>

    </style>
    <style name="MyCustomTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: покажите скриншот. Не совсем понятно, что значит "пропадает". Возможно, цвет текта при клике на него просто совпадает с цветом фона?

Comment: @metalurgus добавил

Comment: Я думаю, что проблема со стилем. Его вы не показали.

Comment: @metalurgus сделано

Comment: @metalurgus совсем нет идей?

Comment: попробуйте поменять эти цвета:  <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>

Comment: @metalurgus смена первого атрибута помогла, оформите как ответ, и объясните - почему так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Этот атрибут поумолчанию используется, как цвет "*нажатого*" элемента меню. `@android:color/transparent` - "*прозрачный*" цвет с кодом `#00000000`. Поэтому, пункт меню становился "*прозрачным*" при нажатии.
Если вы не хотите менять этот атрибут для всего приложения, можете задать стиль с нужным значением этого атрибута специально для вашего `NavigationView`